# Excel VBA throws overflow error with a simple division

Tags: excel, vba, integer

Excel 2013. VBA:
This code:

```
Sub test()
On Error GoTo Err:
Dim p As Double

p = (362 * 100) / 2005
Exit Sub
Err:
    If Err.Description <> "" And Err.Source <> "" Then
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, Err.Source
    End If
End Sub
```

Throws Overflow number 6 error. Why?

Comment: because default numeric type is integer, wich is completely retro stuff even on 64 bits excel, when default should be long or double !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is on `362 * 100`. It is considered `Integer` and it is up to `32767`.

Try like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()    
    Dim pct As Double
    pct = (CDbl(362) * 100) / 2005        
End Sub
```

The problem is that if you have any of the following 4 mathematic expressions (`+-/*`) with values under `2^15-1` or `32767`, VBA considers them `Integer` and the result is tried to be parsed to `Integer` as well. (The `Integer` values are actually from `-32768` to `32767`)

Thus, `32767+1` gives an overthrow error. If you try with `32768+1` it will be ok, because `32768` will be parsed to `Long`.

For the power operator, `^`, VBA parses to `Double` and it is quite ok - `2 ^ 10 + 32000`

Comment: Sux but okeey! :), as this is the first answer

Answer (score 3):

Because the `Integer` type in VBA is 16 bits signed, and 36200 overflows its maximum value of 32767. You can avoid this by appending `&` to one of the operands to make it a `Long` literal, for example `(362& * 100) / 2005`.