# Getting Run-Time error 6: Overflow in very simple Excel VBA code (Mac)

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I've gotten a Run-Time Error 6 while running some code, and while debugging I started to take away parts of it, until I was left with this very, very simple code, and still got an error

```
Sub test()

Dim NumberTest As Double

NumberTest = 1 / 2

End Sub
```

Error happens on the third line when I step into the code. Anyone knows what could be causing it? I'm on Excel 2016 for Mac

Comment: Not sure. When I execute this code on my Windows machine with Excel 2013 I'm unable to reproduce the issue (i.e. not getting any errors).

Comment: @Luiz, Seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48583900/excel-vba-throws-overflow-error-with-a-simple-division? Try `NumberTest = cdbl(1 / 2)` or some other variant of the equation `NumberTest = cdbl(1) / 2` (as per the link) and see if the error persists.

Comment: You're dividing two `Integer` literals. Try converting either (or both) to `Double` first, using the `CDbl` conversion function. Are you sure this [mcve] is correctly representative of the actual problem? Real code seldom divides two integer literals like this (you'd conceivably have `Const half As Double = 0.5` instead).

Comment: Alternatively, use `Double` literals. Does `NumberTest = 1# / 2#` still overflow?

Comment: None of those work, I still get the same error... Code runs normally on windows, but I need it to work on Mac

Comment: Try removing spaces around / and if that doesn't work then change the code to Evaluate("1/2"), this will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce the error in Excel version 16.21 (181210). Perhaps if you install updates the problem will be resolved.

To find which version of Excel you have, go to the Excel menu and choose About Excel. You should have version 16.16.4 or 16.16.5 if you have Office 2016. If you have Office 2019 you should have version 16.19 or 16.20. Insider Fast build is 16.21 (181210). If your version is not one of these, use the Help menu and choose Check for Updates. If your version is any 15.x version, checking for updates won't get you updates. You'll have to download a new copy of AutoUpdate from Microsoft.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJUdZ.png)